# Show for a sequence of measurable functions, there exists a sequence of positive real numbers such that their ratio goes to zero.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and consider a sequence of measurable functions $f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. Show there exists a sequence of positive real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{f_n(\omega)}{a_n}\to 0 \quad \text{as}\quad  n\to \infty \quad\text{for almost every  } \omega.
\end{equation}
Thus there must exist a subset $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $\frac{f_n(\omega)}{a_n}\to 0$ for all $\omega\in A$ while $\mu(A^c)=0$. I thought of something like this: We have that the set
\begin{equation}
A_n=\{\omega\in\Omega|f(\omega)>n\}
\end{equation}
is measurable and decreasing: $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$, so the limit exists. Let $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$, note that A is also measurable and that $\mu(A)=0$(?). In addition, for $\omega \in A^c$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(w)}{n}=0$. Is something like this correct, any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $A_n = \{\omega \in \Omega; f_{\color{red}{n}}(\omega)>n\}$...? The measure of this set does not necessarily converge to $0$ and, in general, the inclusion $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Show that for any measurable function $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that $$\mu \left( \left\{ \omega \in \Omega; \left| \frac{g(\omega)}{R} \right| \geq \epsilon \right\} \right) \leq \epsilon^2.$$ Hint: Use the continuity of the measure $\mu$ (i.e. a similiar approach as you suggested in your solution attempt).
2. By Step 1, there exists a sequence $(R_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (0,\infty)$ such that $$\mu \left( \left\{ \omega \in \Omega; \left| \frac{f_n(\omega)}{R_n} \right| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\} \right) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$ for all $n \geq 1$. In particular, $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu \left( \left\{ \omega \in \Omega; \left| \frac{f_n(\omega)}{R_n} \right| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\} \right) < \infty.$$
3. Apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma to conclude that $$\frac{f_n}{R_n} \to 0 \qquad \text{$\mu$-almost everywhere}.$$